# Getting started with OpenRasta

Tags: openrasta

Hi can anyone suggest ways of getting started with OpenRasta?

Perhaps articles, tutorials, sample apps & documentation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have some blog posts:

- [OpenRasta Introduction](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2008/04/using-rasta-1-introduction.html)
- [OpenRasta - How to speak REST](http://codebetter.com/blogs/kyle.baley/archive/2009/04/19/openrasta-or-how-to-speak-rest.aspx)
- [Whats so good about OpenRasta](http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2010/02/whats-so-good-about-openrasta.html)
- [OpenRasta Introduction](http://blog.muonlab.com/2010/02/12/openrasta-code-camp-at-huddle/)
- [Handlers and OperationResults in OpenRasta](http://blog.muonlab.com/2010/02/16/handlers-and-operation-results-in-openrasta/)
- [A better ActionResult: OpenRasta edition](http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2009/12/better-actionresult-open-rasta-edition_15.html)
- [What I like about OpenRasta](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/05/29/what-i-like-about-openrasta.aspx)

And some videos:

- [OpenRasta demo at SkillsMatter](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/openrasta)
- [OpenRasta - An MVC Framework with strong opinions](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/openrasta-an-mvc-framework-with-strong-opinions)
- [The OpenRasta Framework for Building ReST-ful Applications](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX19)

Comment: Thanks. The link that Sebastien gave is obviously the greatest place to start but it's nice seeing what others are doing with it and I find videos often useful. 

There's also more links on the OpenRasta trac http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta#PeopletalkingaboutOpenRasta

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki

Are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

[Creating Web Sites with Open Rasta](http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/?id=6F6790C2-BB0F-46C8-8373-E00341777A59) (1h from [NDC](http://www.ndc2010.no/agenda.aspx?cat=1071&id=-1&day=3728) June 2010 with [Sebastien Lambla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48213/serialseb))